# AX Pass Value from Form to Report

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, ssrs-2012

i have a problem with AX.
i'm newbie of this technology
i'm trying to build a form like this and when i click(button), i wanna send the RecID to SSRS Report

[image]

I have implemented the DataProvider Class, the Contract Class and the Controller Class.

I test this class with a defined value in the code, and it work,
  but now i no have idea **how pass this TextValue to the class**.

if you need more information, comment and i'll update the post!

Comment: Have you considered studying a working example? There are hundreds of working reports in AX (most look bad, but anyway).

Comment: Jan do you have some simple form to suggest to me on AX?

Comment: Not really, but find a (simple) report, behaving similar to what you want. Search for the word 'contract' witch is the term used to transfer variables as report parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You should define those fields in the DataContract so AX would build the form for you and pass them as parameters to the Report.

Another way is to create some methods in the form to access those fields in the form. And in [prePromptModifyContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/srsreportruncontroller.prepromptmodifycontract.aspx) of you controller call thos methods.

I believe that the first options is more suitable